# Do the \d and \w metacharacters include international characters?

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression, icu

In Java it appears `\d` = `[0-9]` and `\w` = `[A-Za-z_]`, is this the same for iOS and ICU?

I don't want to include international characters yet the documentation only includes Unicode references.

Comment: is this swift or Obj-C?

Comment: From what I remember, `(?U)` in Java and `(?u)` in Swift enable `\w` to be Unicode aware. Else, `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: It should take you approximately one line of code to test if `\w` matches `é` for instance.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski True but this wouldn't tell me what it includes specifically.

Comment: @Deco either `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` or `[\p{L}\p{N}_]` depending on whether Unicode is enabled or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` by default, and it only matches Unicode letters once you use `(?U)` (`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag), see [this demo](http://ideone.com/G4sARG):

```
String s = "abc śął"
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?U)\\w+", "")); // " "
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\w+", ""));     // " śął"
```

In Objective-C, `\w` will match Unicode letters:

```
NSString * s = @"abcśął";
NSString * rx = @"\\w+";
NSPredicate * rxTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", rx];
if ([rxTest evaluateWithObject:s]) {
 NSLog (@"yes");
}
else
{
 NSLog (@"no");
}
```

[This will print `yes`.](https://ideone.com/qtPrBR) Also, see [the official reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/):

> `\w`    Match a word character. Word characters are `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}]`.

The `\p{}` syntax matches Unicode symbols falling under some category. So, `\w` basically matches Unicode letters (`\p{Ll}` - lowercase letters, `\p{Lu}` - uppercase letter, `\p{Lt}` -  titlecase letters, `\p{Lo}` - other letters), and digits (`\p{Nd}`). In fact, `\w` in iOS will also match `_` (it is strange it does not appear in the documentation).

**The rule of thumb**:

- If you need to only match ASCII letters and underscore, use an unambiguous `[a-zA-Z_]`.
- If you want to make sure you only match ASCII digits, use an unambiguous `[0-9]`.